# How to make a component generic and make it's variables accessible from outside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these 2 functions in my app.

```
const onAdd = (val: Val)=> {
        console.log(val)
        return val
}
const onDelete = (val: Val)=> {
        console.log(val)
        return val
}
```

I want to make this component generic so if it's used anywhere, these functions can return the values easily which can be further worked upon.

```
<Adder data={val} onAdd={onAdd} onDelete={onDelete}/>
```

How do i make it so that when a person uses this component and wants that particular val on delete, he can make his own function on it?

Comment: For me, it is not clear what you want to achieve. What is "this component". You do not how any components except `Adder`. Are you asking how one would implement `Adder` so you could pass `onAdd` and `onDelete`?

Comment: How do you determine when to add and when to delete? A button press?

Comment: It is important to you exactly describe what you want and what you have tried so far, why it didn't work, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any state management library like Redux, mobx, flux for this. React also provides inbuild Context API. You can store the value in any state management and can provide the methods to update it as well.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that [How to make a component generic and make it's variables accessible from outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68707467/how-to-make-a-component-generic-and-make-its-variables-accessible-from-outside#comment121424463_68707467) and [How to make a component generic and make it's variables accessible from outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68707467/how-to-make-a-component-generic-and-make-its-variables-accessible-from-outside/68707846#comment121424509_68707467) are true.

```
type Val = number;

interface AdderProps {
  data: Val;
  onAdd(val: Val): void;
  onDelete(val: Val): void;
}

function Adder(props: AdderProps): ReactElement {
  const {data, onAdd, onDelete} = props;
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <span>{data}</span>
      <button onClick={() => onAdd(data + 1)}>Add</button>
      <button onClick={() => onDelete(data - 1)}>Delete</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function App(): ReactElement {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Val>(0);
  
  return <Adder data={data} onAdd={setData} onDelete={setData} />;
}
```

If this satisfies what you want, I would recommend replacing the `onAdd` and `onDelete` with a single `onChange` prop:

```
interface AdderProps {
  data: Val;
  onChange(val: Val): void;
}

function Adder(props: AdderProps): ReactElement {
  const {data, onChange} = props;
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <span>{data}</span>
      <button onClick={() => onChange(data + 1)}>Add</button>
      <button onClick={() => onChange(data - 1)}>Delete</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function App(): ReactElement {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Val>(0);
  
  return <Adder data={data} onChange={setData} />;
}
```